# COCOS2DX, Adding Sprite To Parent

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have created the ball sprite as a parent sprite and i need to add a child sprite in all the boundary of the parent sprite. by defaultly the parent image png it take as square shape, But i want to add like circle. What i can do in COCOS2d-X to add child around circle boundry?

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing a circle, you can use this [post as reference](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-do-i-draw-a-circle/32281). This drawn circle has a perfect round boundary. Attach that to your parent circle image (the one with square boundaries) and set it to invisible. Now you can use attach the child sprites to that invisible drawn circle. It will have the illusion that the child sprites are attached to the circle image.

Comment: thanks #Adi Mabfalin. I check with my code and reply to u about successfully finished.

Comment: Dear #Adi Mabfalin if i set invisible to that clippingnode then the parent image also invisible?